# Storing iBooks in iCloud

Tags: icloud, storage, books

Can iBooks be saved to iCloud then deleted on my iPad but still be available on iCloud? The reason for asking this is that my iPad is running out of space, so I want to store my iBooks elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

With the release of iOS 9.3 iBooks now supports storing PDF and ePub files in iCloud. You should be prompted to enable it when you launch iBooks after performing the update. If not then you can enable it via the Settings App under iCloud > iCloud Drive > iBooks.